# Conditional probability calculation example

Tags: probability, integration, conditional-probability

The joint density function of two random variables $X$ and $Y$ is

$$f_{X,Y}(x,y)=\begin{cases}0.0009x(1+y), \quad\text{if $(x,y)\in \Omega$}\\
0, \quad\text{else}\end{cases}$$
and the marginal distributions are
$$f_X(x)=0.0036(21x-2x^2-x\sqrt{x}),\quad\text{and}\quad f_Y(y)=0.0009(1+y)\frac{y^4}{512}$$
where
$$\Omega\{(x,y):4\sqrt{x}<y \quad\text{and}\quad 0<y<12\}$$
I want to calculate the following conditional probability
$$P(X<4|Y>4)$$
My idea was to use the following definition

If $X$,$Y$ are continuous random variables such that $X\in A$ and $Y\in B$, then the conditional probability is defind as
$$P(X\in A | Y\in B)=\frac{\int_B P(X\in A|y)f_Y(y)dy}{\int_Bf_Y(y)dy}$$
in my case this is translated to
$$P(X<4|Y>4)=\frac{\int_{4}^{12} P(X<4|y)f_Y(y)dy}{\int_{4}^{12}f_Y(y)dy}$$
But I struggle to calculate the numerator $\int_{4}^{12} P(X<4|y)f_Y(y)dy$ because of the integration limits. Can anybody help me to solve this simple problem?

Comment: In a solution that I have found, they solve the problem by seperating the space of $y$ in two subspaces that are $[4,8]$ and $[8,12]$, why?

Comment: you are working with wrong joint density function. $ \displaystyle \int_0^{12}\int_0^{y^2/16} 0.0009x(1+y) \ dx \ dy \ne 1$

Comment: what? how can you say so?

Comment: Let me mention something more $X$ and $Y$ are not independent

Comment: Math lover you are totally wrong, it holds that $\int_0^9\int_{4\sqrt{x}}^{12}0.0009x(1+y)dxdy=1$. You can check this if you like!

Comment: The problem is well defined!

Comment: You probably meant $\int_0^9\int_{4\sqrt{x}}^{12} 0.0009x (1+y) \ dy \ dx$? That integral is same as what I wrote earlier and does not add to $1$ at least based on my calculation

Comment: Now I check on WolframAlpha and it gives $\dfrac{24057}{25000}$

Comment: Ok you are doing something wrong then....this can not be...I haven't use wolframalpha but this is from a textbook...it can not be wrong...and I have done the calculations by myself, with bare hands, not a programm and it gives $1$...

Comment: Your textbook has naively written it as $0.0009$. That is not correct. Instead they should have written it as $\dfrac{5}{5364}$. What you and your textbook do not realize that $0.00093...$ and $0.0009$ are not the same. You did approximation too when you used your bare hands for calculation. In any case, I have an extended discussion in comments warning but if you are interested in understanding it better and how you could solve rest of it in a simpler way, please ping me in chat. Good luck!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126406/discussion-between-hunger-learn-and-math-lover).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keeping the point on joint density function that I made in comments aside, to find $\small P(X \lt 4 | Y \gt 4)$, you can either work with marginal density or directly with the joint density function.

[image]

If you look at the diagram, the shaded region together (marked $1$ and $2$) will give you $ \small P(Y \gt 4)$. Also the region shaded in light blue (marked $1$) will give us $\small P((X \lt 4) \cap (Y \gt 4))$.

Given the region shaded in light green is $ \small P(X \gt 4)$,  $\small P((X \lt 4) \cap (Y \gt 4)) = P(Y \gt 4) - P(X \gt 4)$

So, $\displaystyle \small P(Y \gt 4) = \int_4^{12} \int_0^{y^2/16} f(x,y) \ dx \ dy \ \ $ ...($i$)

$\displaystyle \small P((X \lt 4) \cap (Y \gt 4)) = P(Y \gt 4) - \int_8^{12} \int_4^{y^2/16} f(x,y) \ dx \ dy \ \ $ ...($ii$)

dividing ($ii$) by ($i$) will give us $ \small P(X \lt 4 | Y \gt 4)$